# How to breakdown List<List<String>> rows

Tags: java, android, list, sqlite, arraylist

So I have a code where my variables var1, var2, and var3 goes to a `List<String> temp`. And for every click of a button, another batch of variables will go to `temp` and `temp` goes to `List<List<String>> rows` at the end of the function. Note that I can click the button as many times I want and the process `temp.add(var1); temp.add(var2); ... rows.add(temp);` will run.

Now, I want to break down `rows` and save all of the data of `temp` to my database.

here is a part of my code:

```
ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
temp.add(itemnameCol);
temp.add(itempriceCol+"");
temp.add(dialogVar+"");
t2Rows.add(temp);
```

here is the insert method

```
public void addItem(String itemIn, String itemProd, String itemQuan){
    cv.clear();
    cv.put(INVOICE_NUM_ITEM,itemIn);
    cv.put(PRODUCT_ID_ITEM,itemProd);
    cv.put(PRODUCT_QUANTITY_ITEM,itemQuan);
    dbw.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME_ITEM, null, cv);

}
```

Comment: I did not get your question ,You are storing list of list and the list contain all the value to be insert into row then what is the problem ,Can you please clarify

Comment: My problem is that I can't think of a way to insert those values into my database. You see, they are inside a list **that is inside a list**. So I'm having trouble getting the data so that I could save them into my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a for loop. Try this.

```
String[] itemCode12345 = itemCode123.toArray(new String[itemCode123.size()]); 
String[] itemQuan12345 = itemQuan123.toArray(new String[itemQuan123.size()]);

for(int a=0; a< t2Rows.size(); a++){
    db_data.addItem(abc+"",itemCode12345[a],itemQuan12345[a]);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! by the way, I used this to make it run 
            `String[] itemCode12345 = itemCode123.toArray(new String[itemCode123.size()]);
            String[] itemQuan12345 = itemQuan123.toArray(new String[itemQuan123.size()]);`